# How can I loop through a calendar to open files on VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to loop through dates and open up files based on the date within the loop. For instance the loop may be for 9/1/19 -> 9/10/19 and the files would be "090119" -> "091019" I can open the files individually but I cant seem to figure out the loop part of it. Also the way I am opening the files now is by typing in an inputbox "**'090119**".

Is there a way I can use a calendar to select the dates, then based on those dates assign a variable for the month, day, and year and then use concatenate to add the variables so they are in the mmddyy format. Is there a preset formula or method to loop through days this way so that it knows the amount of days in each month 30 vs 31, etc..

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what code you have so far tried? Seems like you want a `Step` for this one.

Comment: You don't need to concatenate to get a date in mmddyy format, use `Format`. You can use `DateAdd` to increment dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the days with this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub IterateDays()
    Dim datFrom As Date: datFrom = DateSerial(2013, 4, 5)
    Dim datTo As Date: datTo = DateSerial(2013, 5, 4)
    Dim datDay As Date: datDay = datFrom
    While datDay <= datTo
        Dim strDay As String: strDay = Format(datDay, "mmddyy")
        Debug.Print strDay
        datDay = DateAdd("d", 1, datDay)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Yay for dates `As Date` and actual date-math. I'd recommend `Do While...Loop` over `While...Wend` though... be it just because `Wend` is weird and you can't `Exit While` but you can `Exit Do`.

Comment: I know that a Date is actually a Double and you get the same iteration by adding 1.0 as the integer part is the day and the fraction part is the time of the day, however, not everyone remembers that immediately and confidently. Even if that gives a minimal efficiency, it is not worth the loss of clear intent.

Comment: If you want to exit, you can rewrite it to `Do While`. I just don't like it because it's two words.

Comment: Unfortunately what people usually do instead is introduce a label and a `GoTo` jump...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without custom calendar controls would be to create a DialogBox with `FROM` and `TO` date calendar pickers, a Button to add simple date, and a ListBox with added dates or date periods ... a `START` Button to start you process to create a system file for each date in ListBox or dates in period added in ListBox. You can also add a `DELETE` Button to remove incorreclty date or period added previously in ListBox.

To create multiple system file after having pressed `START` Button, you must only write a code that iterates smartly throw each date and period selected and added in date and period ListBox.

The ListBox can contain following lines

```
2018-10-12
2018-10-06 -> 2018-10-14
2018-12-04
```

The are two parts in this solution.

In the first part, you write a DialogBox to fill a ListBox.

In the second part (after having clicked on Start Button), you create multiple files.